# How to tag AWS ECS for cost explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I want to calculate my Elastic Container Service costs using tags in Cost Explorer.

I have tagged the cluster, the services, the tasks and the task definitions. It is running on Fargate.

However, in the Cost Explorer, the service type: Elastic Container Service does not consider the tags I've mentioned above.

Please help.

**tldr: How do I calculate all ECS cost for a particular cluster in Cost Explorer?**